# Error in printing key value in python dict: String indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key-value

I am trying to access all the keys and values from a dictionary in python individually. The data was in excel format so I converted it into a dictionary. In the `tower.json` file I am getting the output as:

```
[{"Item": "LD1C", "Rel": "40410"}, {"Item": "LD1D", "Rel": "40411"}, …..}]
```

How do I print the various `items` and the `rels` individually?

```
import xlrd
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\eumukar\Desktop\test data.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

tower_list = []

for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
    tower = OrderedDict()
    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
    tower['Item'] = row_values[0]
    tower['EUtranCellRelation'] = row_values[1]

    tower_list.append(tower)


dat = json.dumps(tower_list)

with open(r'C:\Users\eumukar\Desktop\tower.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(dat)
```

While trying to print the key/Items I am writing this and getting an error:

```
for i in dat:
    print(i,dat[i])

 1 for i in dat:
----> 2     print(i,dat[i])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `json.dumps` returns a string

Comment: ```json.dumps``` will give you str

Comment: Use tower json to parse

Answer (score 0):

the reason of error is that objects is not enumerated means it doesn't have indices
try below code

```
for i in enumerate(dat):
    print(i,dat[i])
```

for more details you can visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/

Comment: The same error is coming but I will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you accessing `dat[i]`? Iterators don't yield range indices, they yield values. So `i` is not an index it's the actual value.

Furthermore `dat` is a string here, iterating strings yields individual characters (as strings), why are you doing that?

PS: when using text-mode IO (`open` without the `'b'` flag), you really want to provide the `encoding` parameter explicitely to avoid bad surprises.